# Cloudera and Docker

Tags: docker, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I want to run Cloudera using a Docker image (specifically, the cloudera/quickstart image).

However, on Docker Hub I can only find beta versions:

https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudera/quickstart/tags/

What's the correct way of getting a more up-to-date image?

Should I just download a beta image and then install parcels? Would I do that using Docker Compose? If so, can I find instructions for that online?

Or is there a completely different way to solve this?

Comment: You don't have to separately install Parcels. It is a quickstart. It comes with all pre-installed parcels.

Comment: Well, in my parcels view I can see that there is a CDH 5 parcel which seems to update CDH to the latest version. And I would like to use the latest version available...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run Cloudera Quickstart within Docker, follow the instructions on that page:
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/quickstart_docker_container.html

Forget about your concerns regarding the "beta" tag. These tags are there, because the Docker image of Cloudera Quickstart is in beta mode. However, the CDH version in there is not. 
You will find this out on your own, once you run the container and check the CDH version inside.